# How to run system command in Cake build?

Tags: cakebuild

I couldn't find any information related with running custom system command on this site: [cakebuild.net/dsl](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/)

How can I do it?

---

The real command I want to run is 'upx mproject.exe'

Answer (score 8):

If I have understood you correctly, then what you are looking for is the Process Aliases that exist within Cake:

http://cakebuild.net/dsl/process/

These allow you to start any arbitrary process from within your Cake script.

Another option, would be to create a Cake Addin that wraps the tool that you are trying to execute.

Comment: Just added the information.
I saw the Process DSL, its name is a little bit low level, I was expecting something like 'exec' or 'system'. Anyway I will have a try.

Comment: Process is really referring to the Operating System Process that is created when the tool is ran.

Comment: Thanks. I will use it.